# Issue while filtering multiple columns if one of the fields is Indexed

Tags: error, filter, 2016, ootb, sharepoint-views

I have a list in SharePoint 2016 with over 35k items and around 15 custom Fields.  I have a view that displays only around 300 - 400 items. When users filter the view using the column filters, the filters works fine except when they first apply a filter in one of the Indexed columns and then apply a filter in another column, in this case the filter won’t get apply unless a second option is selected in that column.

This is the example:
Columns:
(Indexed) Status, Choice Field.
Assigned To, User Field.

Step 1: Select “Not Started” in the Status Filter

Result: The List gets filtered and only shows “Not Started” items.

Step 2: Select “User A” in the Assigned To Filter

Result: The List is not updated, all users still shows.

Step 3: Select “User B” in the Assigned To Filter

Result: The List is updated and only shows “Not Started” items for “User A” and “User B”

Additional Information:

The error occurs with any column combination that starts by filtering Status, not only with the Assigned to Column.

During Step 2 there is a 601 error on the call /_layouts/15/inplview.aspx

ULS shows the following errors:

Error while executing web part: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2…

And

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@L6TXPt4".  Incorrect syntax near 'Nvp'.

I’ll appreciate any suggestion to help me solve this issue, Thank you.